# c# Псевдогенератор

Tags: c#, winforms, gui

Каким образом возможно обойти повторение чисел?В ПГCЧ.

Comment: Проверкой вхождения в уже полученные числа

Comment: Либо, если чисел надо нагенерировать много, добавить их все в список и перемешать его

Comment: Никак. Случайные числа принципиально могут повторяться. Если они не повторяются, то это уже не случайные числа.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)Мудрил с ограничениями и так,и сяк)Да, тогда это уже будет походу не псевдо))

Answer (score 0):

Обычно делается примерно по подобному шаблону, вместо `int` можно использовать любой класс:

```
        List<int> numList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 7, 23, 45, 78, 90, 444, 999 };
        Random rng = new Random();
        while (numList.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = numList[rng.Next(0, numList.Count)];
            numList.Remove(item);
            // Делаем что нужно с 'item'
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Comment: так себе пример

Comment: @pashagoroshko Ну, напишите свой, обсудим ваш пример.

Comment: написал ниже. Просто в вашем примере по сути нельзя обратиться повторно к вашему коду, ведь числа будут возвращаться те же самые

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать список случайных чисел и убрать из них дубликаты:

```
        var random = new Random();
        var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => random.Next(1, 1000)).Distinct().ToArray();
```